# Clarification on PostgreSQL update join statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't seem to find any documentation that clearly elaborate how certain update-join statements work in PostgreSQL. Suppose there are three tables in a database: `professors`, `classes`, and `classrooms`. In the `professors` table, one of the attributes is a `class_id`, a foreign key referencing the `classes` table. In the `classes` table, there is a `classroom_id`, referencing the `classrooms` table. This is the command I'm interested in:

```
UPDATE classes c SET year = 2
FROM classes cl
JOIN professors on cl.class_id = professors.class_id
JOIN classrooms on cl.classroom_id = classrooms.classroom_id
WHERE cl.class_id = c.class_id
```

This seems to calculate `X = inner join(inner join(classes, professors), classrooms)` and updates `year = 2` for every class that is included in `X`. Is this correct? Furthermore, I don't understand how the `WHERE` clause accomplishes this. Why does this work, and why don't I have to use the `IN` keyword to accomplish this task?

I would appreciate a simple and systematic explanation of what an `UPDATE... FROM... JOIN... WHERE` statement does in PostgreSQL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your data model, because it seems that a professor could teach more than one course.

That said, your query is

```
UPDATE classes c
    SET year = 2
FROM classes c2 JOIN
     professors p
     ON c2.class_id = p.class_id JOIN
     classrooms cr
     ON c2.classroom_id = cr.classroom_id
WHERE c2.class_id = c.class_id;
```

The `FROM` clause is doing a `JOIN`, just as you would expect.  You could check the results by using `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM . . . <the FROM clause here>
```

What else is happening?  Well, the `UPDATE` is telling Postgres to update the table `classes`.  Ignore the fact that `classes` is in the `FROM` clause (that is a different reference).

How does it know which records to update?  Well, the `WHERE` clause is saying to update the rows that match the `FROM`.  In this case, the `JOIN`s are doing the filtering.

You can also express this logic with `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE classes c
    SET year = 2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM professors p WHERE c.class_id = p.class_id) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM classrooms cr WHERE c.classroom_id = cr.classroom_id);
```

Personally I think the intention is clearer with this version.

Comment: Doesn't your version update everything in the classes table, since there do exist classes with professors and rooms? I would like to *only* update those with non-NULL values of classes and rooms.

Comment: @paulinho . . . This should be doing the same thing as your query.  `NULL` values match neither `INNER JOIN` conditions nor `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanks! Now what if I needed to replace one of the inner joins with another join, say, a left join?

Comment: @paulinho . . . New questions should be asked as *questions*, with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this explanation is really systematic, but here goes.

When you UPDATE classes, it already knows what table you are dealing with. In practice I don't generally reference the table again after FROM but I'm sure there are cases where it might be preferable to do a join than use WHERE.

The WHERE clause in your example simply makes sure that both instances of the classes table are dealing with the same rows. Otherwise I guess it would be an outer join.

In your example, there seems no point to the other JOINS. Often there is, when you might want to constrain the update to certain professors, as in WHERE professors.professor='Einstein'.

Finally, as I mentioned, I don't usually use the updated table a second time, rather I'd use.

```
UPDATE classes c SET year = 2
 FROM professors, classrooms 
 WHERE on c.class_id = professors.class_id
    AND c.classroom_id = classrooms.classroom_id
```

Works fine for me, but there may be cases where the other syntax is preferable, especially if you want a left join or some such.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The effect of the other joins is to basically 'filter out' all classes without a room. So only classes with a room and a professor are updated. My original intention was just to update any classes with a room and a professor: how would you go about doing this PostgreSQL, if my way is not what you'd normally do?

Comment: That make sense then, if there are Nulls in the room numbers. I remember, although it was quite some time ago that I switched to PostgreSQL, that in SQL-Server the syntax was quite more straightforward. Especially when you consider in PostgreSQL there is also DELETE FROM table USING .... which is the same concept with different words.